# how to use partition and keep consistency

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

[image]

I have a dataset of all the dates from 1982 until today, in the CALENDAR table. Each record (date) in the table had an indication of whether it's a business day or not. I am trying to number the rows so that it starts from 1 and continuously run through the dates, but when it gets to a date that is NOT a working day, it will receive the same number as the previous date, and continue the numbering - NOT partition and restart the numbering.
This is the code I used:

```
SELECT t1.thedate,
        t1.working_day,
        Rank() Over(PARTITION BY Working_Day ORDER BY TheDate) AS test
FROM CAL t1
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: give the table or sample data and expected result so it elaborates and comprehensive

Comment: so please add dummy data instead of actual it's may help you and other

Comment: It worked - I edited my Q and added a pic... thanks.

Comment: If you got the answer then answer your question and mark it as right so it helps others who will face same problem in the future.

Comment: NO. I managed to add a picture of the result query - I DID NOT answer my question...

Comment: You have added the query result but can please add the expected result Because what you actually want elaborates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use RANK, simply sum over 1/0:

```
sum(case when Working_Day = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)
over (ORDER BY TheDate
      rows unbounded preceding)
```

Or a bit shorter, count non-null rows:

```
count(case when Working_Day = 'Y' then 1 end)
over (ORDER BY TheDate
      rows unbounded preceding)
```